# an issue with Listview class

Tags: listview, android-studio

hellow .. i'm having a problem with Listview class ... the problem is with imports i get for example : cannot resolve symbol nullable in:

```
import android.annotation.Nullable;
```

same this with :

```
import com.google.android.collect.Lists;
import android.annotation.IdRes;
import android.annotation.NonNull;
import android.util.MathUtils;
import android.view.ViewHierarchyEncoder;
import android.view.ViewRootImpl;
```

this is my dependencies :

```
    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
    compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.1.6'
    compile 'com.intellij:annotations:+@jar'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding;
   `compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.4.0'`
for `import android.annotation.Nullable;`

Other problems that you are facing with imports are probably related to your dependencies.